# Function not available after document.body.appendChild(scriptElement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I am using for dynamically including script tag with `src` in my HTML page. There is a function in that newly imported javascript file that I want to use:

```
var scriptFile= document.createElement("script");
scriptFile.src = "something.js";
var something=document.body.appendChild(scriptFile);
```

something.js contains a function called `doSomething()`. Now when I call this function immediately after the `appendChild` above, it say `doSomething` is not defined. However, when I fire it from the Chrome console, it executes successfully. I am not sure why is this happening.

Comment: When you add a script file to the document, it has to fetch the resource and compile it before it is available for execution.

Comment: But shouldn't the execution pause till then?

Comment: Your results should answer your own question, :)

Comment: Right, But how do I overcome this? How can I wait till its fetched and then use the function?

Comment: Aside from any vanilla js method of accounting for this, jQuery does offer the http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ which would allow you to put your logic in the success handler, which would execute after the file is loaded and compiled.

Comment: The loading of the script by the browser happens outside the thread that is executing the script to place that tag in the document. Because of this, it does not 'see' the new method being added until after the file is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

When you append the `script` tag with the source, first the source will be parsed and compiled which is an asyn process ( non blocking ).

If you try to invoke the method immediately this would throw an error as the source has not been compiled yet.

Bind a `load` event which gets triggered when the script is available. This will make sure you are running the contents of the script tag only after it has completely loaded.

```
var scriptFile= document.createElement("script");

scriptFile.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Script is ready to execute');

    // invoke your function here
}); 

scriptFile.src = "something.js";
var something=document.body.appendChild(scriptFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen for `onload`

```
var scriptFile= document.createElement("script")
scriptFile.src = "something.js"
document.body.appendChild(scriptFile)
scriptFile.onload = () => {
   // call something.js functions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for example with Arrow function!